# TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById() throws exception in a Unity application

Tags: c#, timezone, unity-game-engine

If I execute this code in a C# console application, it works fine.

```
TimeZoneInfo easternZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
Console.WriteLine(easternZone.DisplayName);
```

However, when I use the same method in a Unity application, an exception is thrown:

```
System.TimeZoneNotFoundException: Exception of type 'System.TimeZoneNotFoundException' was thrown.
  at System.TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneByFileName (System.String id, System.String filepath) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById (System.String id) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  ...
```

A curious thing that I've noticed is that the exception is thrown in a method named "FindSystemTimeZoneByFileName" when the MSDN documentation explicitly says that the information is retrieved from the Registry.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Unity applications use Mono, and can target non-Windows systems - so the registry information is not always available.  It appears that Mono will use whatever time zone information is available on the system, whether that happens to be Windows time zones, or IANA time zones - so, you may need to check for one or the other, or both:

```
TimeZoneInfo easternZone;

try
{
    easternZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
}
catch (TimeZoneNotFoundException)
{
    easternZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("America/New_York");
}
```

Of course, you can reverse these if you typically are going to be running on non-Windows platforms.  If neither are found, then it will still throw an exception.

You can review [the list of IANA time zones here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).  You may also want to read [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) to understand the distinction.

***Update***: As [Shaul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50151501/634824) pointed out, you can now use my [TimeZoneConverter](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TimeZoneConverter/) library to accomplish this.  While the above code is no longer required, you can now simply do this instead:

```
TimeZoneInfo easternZone = TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo(timeZoneName);
```

The `timeZoneName` parameter can be *either* `America/New_York` or `Eastern Standard Time`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer and the links you have provided. I was very confident that it would solve the problem, but unfortunately it hasn't. In fact, I realized that I couldn't even get the list of available time zones using `TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()`. I guess that the problem is not just on Mono but something else related with Unity or any other library that we are using in the project. I'll keep digging,

Comment: I've invested some more time on this issue and found that, in fact, this is a Unity bug, as reported here: https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/win-system-dot-timezoneinfo-does-not-return-any-time-zones

Comment: Thanks for following up.  Let us know if they fix it.  :)

Comment: You might want to see if [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) can run within Unity.  That would give you an alternative option anyway.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint props to you to promote other library as well.

Answer (score 8):

For the record, there's a nice little package called [TimeZoneConverter](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TimeZoneConverter/) that will do this for you without having to catch exceptions:

```
if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux))
{
    timeZoneName = TZConvert.WindowsToIana(timeZoneName);
}
var zoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneName);
```

Comment: FYI, version 2.0.0 and newer have the os platform check built-in, so you can just write `zoneInfo = TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo(timeZoneName)` instead.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint Any suggestion if this is the case, and I'm still seeing the exception?