# Access Current System Time Zone

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, timezone, system, monodevelop

Basically I can able to detect list of system time zones using following code:

```
foreach(TimeZoneInfo info in tz)
    Debug.Log("time zone id : " + info.Id + " display name : " + info.DisplayName);
```

Running this code, I have following output in console.

[image]

In this list, I want to know, which one is my current system is following?
Because I want specific information about that time zone. As like in following code, I was written clear "Asia/Kolkata".

```
TimeZoneInfo infos = System.TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Asia/Kolkata");
```

By running which code, I can able to get "Asia/Kolkata" as output?

**EDIT:** I was already using NodaTime here and code running for this purpose.

```
  // Create a NodaTime DateTimeZoneSource object for IANA time zone names
    var dateTimeZoneSource = TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.Default;

    // Get the Windows time zone by name (or use TimeZoneInfo.Local)
    var timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time");

    // Convert between Windows and IANA time zone names
    var tzdbTimeZoneInfo = dateTimeZoneSource.MapTimeZoneId(timeZoneInfo);

    Console.WriteLine(tzdbTimeZoneInfo);
```

But in this, I am getting exception regarding,

> Exception of type 'System.TimeZoneNotFoundException' was thrown.

I am using Mac system and editor as Mono Develop - Unity and my target devices are iPhones.

Answer (score 4):

Using the code below you can get local TimeZoneInfo object.

```
TimeZoneInfo infos = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
```

Comment: using this, I am getting "Local" in output, I want "Asia/Kolkata" in output.

Comment: use infos.DisplayName property to get the display name from TimeZoneInfo object.

Comment: Close.  Use `Id`, not `DisplayName`

Comment: @MattJohnson, it is not displaying Asia/Kolkata like that.

Comment: @Siddharth - `TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id` is indeed the correct API to use.  What does it return in Unity?  There is [an open bug related to `TimeZoneInfo` in Unity](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/win-system-dot-timezoneinfo-does-not-return-any-time-zones) - though about a different part of the problem.  Still, this may be related.  See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35043022/634824).

Comment: @MattJohnson, I am getting "Local" word in output. Let me check above links.

Comment: @MattJohnson, I want "Asia/Kolkata" in output and they are passing as argument that thing. I want as return statement.

Comment: @MattJohnson, Using linked answer, how can I figure our which time zone is working and which one not because I want to run my game in all time zones.

Comment: I didn't add an answer of my own because I don't work with Unity, so I don't know for certain.  My understanding is that there's a bug in Unity and this is broken.  I don't know much more than that. Sorry.

Comment: @MattJohnson, its okay, you try to help me that is really big thing for me :)

Comment: See also [this Unity forum thread](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/726640/some-problem-on-timezoneinfolocal.html) where another user states that he belives TimeZoneInfo class is broken in Unity 5.1+.

Answer (score 3):

Set your .NET API compatibility to 4.6. Here are the test results in my iOS device:

```
TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id
Editor: Local
iOS Device: Local

TimeZoneInfo.Local.DisplayName
Editor: Local
iOS Device: (GMT+03:30) Local Time

TimeZoneInfo.Local.StandardName
Editor: +0330
iOS Device: +0330

TimeZoneInfo.Local.DaylightName
Editor: +0430
iOS Device: +0430

TimeZoneInfo.Local.BaseUtcOffset.Hours + ":" + TimeZoneInfo.Local.BaseUtcOffset.Minutes);
Editor: 3:30
iOS Device: 3:30
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe help u this links :

here 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg154758.aspx

and

here

[List of Timezone ID's for use with FindTimeZoneById() in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908343/list-of-timezone-ids-for-use-with-findtimezonebyid-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
TimeZoneInfo infos = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(
             { "Asia/Kolkata", "India Standard Time" });
```

> You can see this link for TimeZoneIds

http://unicode.org/repos/cldr-tmp/trunk/diff/supplemental/zone_tzid.html

Comment: In this FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time") not working, I already given exception in my question.

Comment: Above code contains some syntax error so it can't able to run

Comment: Ok By searching I found a link solve your problem by implementing an helper function you can see this link :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996320/net-timezoneinfo-from-olson-time-zone

Comment: Try to use this `TimeZoneInfo infos = System.TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time");
            Console.WriteLine(infos);`
You will find this properties that can help you
`infos.infos.Id`
`infos.DisplayName`
`infos.BaseUtcOffset`

Comment: @Muhmmad Hassan, TimeZoneInfo infos = System.TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time"); is generating exception for me. I have already mentioned in question.

Answer (score 0):

On window Unity5.1.3 editor, TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones() return empty list. 
TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById() and TimeZoneInfo.CreateCustomTimeZone() both raise System.TimeZoneNotFoundException.
but it work well in android device.

```
private static DateTime ToSeoulTime(DateTime dateUtc, bool ignoreUnspecified = false)
{
    if (ignoreUnspecified == false && dateUtc.Kind == DateTimeKind.Unspecified)
    {
        if (UnityEngine.Application.isEditor)
        {
            throw new Exception("dateUtc.Kind == DateTimeKind.Unspecified");
        }
        else
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.LogWarning("dateUtc.Kind == DateTimeKind.Unspecified");
        }
    }
    try
    {
        var seoulTimezone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Korea Standard Time");
        return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dateUtc, seoulTimezone);
    }
    catch (System.TimeZoneNotFoundException e)
    {
        return new DateTime(dateUtc.AddHours(9).Ticks, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
    }
}
```

Comment: Basically my target platform is iPhone so in that I can able to run this line, var timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time");

Comment: In Unity Editor, I am getting exception like above I have mentioned in my question.

Comment: Using this way, how many time zones I can map? Because I want to cover all timezones.

Comment: I also getting exception 'TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime',I modified my answer,

Answer (score 0):

Update your player settings to use .NET 4.6