# TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones().Count gives 0 for unity android app

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

`TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones().Count` gives 0 for unity android app, is there any permission required from android side to get TimeZone data?

```
Debug.LogError("GetSystemTimeZones... " + System.TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones().Count);
```

**Output :** 
GetSystemTimeZones... 0

Comment: There is a Unity Issue on the matter, it seems that it was not yet fixed but on the comments you can find more about it and probably a workaround: https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/win-system-dot-timezoneinfo-does-not-return-any-time-zones

Comment: @VitorFigueredo this only happens in android app where as **iOS** version of same app works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think this method always returns 0 on Android. Reading on the Documentation for [TimeZoneInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.getsystemtimezones?view=netframework-4.8):

> The GetSystemTimeZones method retrieves all available time zone
>   information from the subkeys of the registry's
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time
>   Zones key on Windows systems and from the ICU Library on Linux and
>   macOS.

As you can see, Android is not mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for information. What will be the workaround for android in this case?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37237223/access-current-system-time-zone/

Comment: Thank you for help, but this is not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

based on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.getsystemtimezones?view=netframework-4.8) it is supposed to return 0 in android! but I saw some people do a workaround to solve this problem. it goes as follow:
you can create a jar with Android Studio and get the timezones you need there and then create a C# script to access that jar file.
[here](https://labs.karmaninteractive.com/creating-android-jar-and-aar-plugins-for-unity-c293bb5258c9) you can find a toturial on how to do it.

although in this scenario there is a drawback, you can only pass Strings with this solution.