# How to get TimeZoneInfo on Android, using Unity 2020.3.0f1?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, timezone

Since the Google Play Leaderboard Servie is in the Pacific Standard Time Zone, I want get the local time there to update a calendar, which unlocks daily levels. Once the player actually launches a level I fetch the time from a server. However at application launch I already wanted to set the time for the calendar. However I just can't seem to get any TimeZoneInfo.

```
        public static DateTime GetDatePacificStandardTime(this DateTime value)
    {
#if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR

        try
        {
            AndroidJavaClass Java = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");

            AndroidJavaObject AndroidActivity = Java.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
            TimeZone timeZone = AndroidActivity.Call<TimeZone>("getTimeZone", "America/Los_Angeles");

            TimeSpan difference = timeZone.GetUtcOffset(value);

            return value.Add(difference);
        }
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            Debug.Log("AndroidActivity.Call failed: " + exception);
        }

        try
        {
            return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(value, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time"));
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Debug.Log("TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById Pacific Standard Time failed: " + exception);
        }

        try
        {
            return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(value, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Pacific Standard Time"));
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Debug.Log("TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById Central Pacific Standard Time failed: " + exception);
        }

        try
        {
            return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(value, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("PST"));
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Debug.Log("TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById PST failed: " + exception);
        }

        try
        {
            return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(value, TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo("PST"));
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Debug.Log("TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo PST failed: " + exception);
        }

        try
        {
            return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(value, TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo("Pacific Standard Time"));
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Debug.Log("TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo Pacific Standard Time failed: " + exception);
        }

        try
        {
            return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(value, TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo("Central Pacific Standard Time"));
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Debug.Log("TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo Central Pacific Standard Time failed: " + exception);
        }

        return value;
#endif
        return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(value, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time"));

    }
```

1. LogCat gives me

   - 03-27 18:44:58.362: I/Unity(25251): AndroidActivity.Call failed: System.Exception: JNI: Unknown signature for type 'System.TimeZone' (obj = System.TimeZone) equal
   - 03-27 18:44:58.362: I/Unity(25251): AndroidActivity.Call failed: System.Exception: JNI: Unknown signature for type 'System.TimeZone' (obj = System.TimeZone) equal
   - 03-27 18:44:58.365: I/Unity(25251): TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById Pacific Standard Time failed: System.TimeZoneNotFoundException: Couldn't read time zone file /usr/share/zoneinfo/Pacific Standard Time ---> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "/usr/share/zoneinfo/Pacific Standard Time".
   - 03-27 18:44:58.367: I/Unity(25251): TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById Central Pacific Standard Time failed: System.TimeZoneNotFoundException: Couldn't read time zone file /usr/share/zoneinfo/Central Pacific Standard Time ---> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "/usr/share/zoneinfo/Central Pacific Standard Time".
   - 03-27 18:44:58.370: I/Unity(25251): TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById PST failed: System.TimeZoneNotFoundException: Couldn't read time zone file /usr/share/zoneinfo/PST ---> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "/usr/share/zoneinfo/PST".
   - 03-27 18:44:58.371: I/Unity(25251): TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo PST failed: System.TimeZoneNotFoundException: Exception of type 'System.TimeZoneNotFoundException' was thrown.
   - 03-27 18:44:58.372: I/Unity(25251): TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo Pacific Standard Time failed: System.TimeZoneNotFoundException: Exception of type 'System.TimeZoneNotFoundException' was thrown.
   - 03-27 18:44:58.373: I/Unity(25251): TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo Central Pacific Standard Time failed: System.TimeZoneNotFoundException: Exception of type 'System.TimeZoneNotFoundException' was thrown.

Comment: I'll have to investigate a bit.  But of what you shown here, only `TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo("Pacific Standard Time")` should work (assuming that is using my TimeZoneConverter` library).  You could also try `TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo("America/Los_Angeles")` or just `TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("America/Los_Angles")` (without TimeZoneConverter).   Can you give any details about the specific Android version and device?  It may simply be missing time zone data.

Comment: Also, which specific Google API are you needing to call that requires Pacific time?  Link to the reference doc please.

Comment: Keep in mind that "Central Pacific Standard Time" is for a few islands in the Pacific ocean such as New Caledonia (UTC+11) which is probably not what you are interested in.  Also, "PST" isn't a valid time zone ID.

Comment: You might want to see [this bug](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/win-system-dot-timezoneinfo-does-not-return-any-time-zones) and investigate using [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org/) with its built-in TZDB provider.  However, I still think there's likely some other way to deal with this.

Comment: Yes thanks! Node time did the trick for me. I used NodaTime.2.4.13. Jon Skeet made 3.x also work, I didn't just now... https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime/issues/1525
I will do some more testing this weekend. I will also try to get your TZConvert to work again in Unity. As you pointed out there is a bug in unity atm, in my android build TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones() returns an empty Collection.

Comment: Thanks again and keep up the good work!

Answer (score 0):

**First solution:**

You can use the `TimeZoneInfo.DisplayName`

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57636587) you can see the outputs of the other `TimeZoneInfo` variables.

**Second solution:**

On the first time opening the app you can get the phone local time with `System.DateTime.Now`, and you know the Google Play Leaderboard Service time zone so you can just save the difference in `PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("timeDifarence", Value);`

Then whenever you need it just use `PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("timeDifarence");` and calculate the time on the machine.